# Is there a function to prevent sheet from being dragged by user?

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

My goal is to disable user ability to resize the sheet by dragging.

What I've tried:

1. use `interactiveDismissDisabled(true)` allow us to prevent the sheet from being dismissed.
2. use `disabled(true)` only prevent us from interacting with the sheet but still able to resize the sheet by dragging.
3. use `.presentationDetents(currentStationViewModel.state == .ARRIVED ? [.large] : [.half, .large], selection: $selectedDetent)` it did not animate, instead it looks like changing view.

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
    VisualCueLocationV2View(
        currentStationViewModel: currentStationViewModel,
        isPotrait: $isPotrait,
        selectedDetent: $selectedDetent
    )
    .presentationDetents([.half, .large], selection: $selectedDetent)
    .presentationCornerRadius(12)
    .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
    .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .half))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a single sheet size, so the drag handle will disappear and the sheet becomes non-dismissable. The sheet will bounce while dragging, but not resize.

`.presentationDetents([.large])`

Comment: The problem is .presentationDetents([.half, .large]) is necessary before `state == .ARRIVED`

Answer (score 0):

You can user a fullScreenCover modifier, it will pop up a whole sheet which will have no drag handle and you can dismiss it by passing a binding or use Environment dismiss property.

.fullScreenCover(isPresented: ) {

// Your view to present

}

Comment: fullScreenCover do not support half presentationDetents.